# How change downlaod folder path in imacro

Tags: imacros

I am using this:

```
-------- ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER=C:\Users\XR556\Desktop\Working<SP>As<SP>on\Auto<SP>Collate<SP>Sheet\ FILE=DownloadReport_{{!NOW:yyyymmdd_hhnnss}} WAIT=YES -------
```

But this is neither saving on giving a path nor giving a file name. Why?

Comment: Are you seeing anything as a result? Where exactly are you using that? Can you be specific about what you expect to see?

Comment: Have you tried a simple way: `ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER=* FILE=* WAIT=YES` . Is it OK?

Comment: ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER=* FILE=* WAIT=YES----- is working fine....... actually i am trying this to download a report from my server, everything this working fine in simple way, but wen i am trying to change the folder path the port is saving on default path only i.e. "C:\Users\Dharmendra\Downloads" , neither it is changing the path nor it is changing the file name.

Comment: Has the user running iMacros rights to write on the target folder? What happens if you change only the file name and keep the default folder?

Comment: yes, its take default folder and file name

Answer (score 0):

@Dharmendra: You need to give an extension to your file. This might be causing your issue.

Try to give an extension based on the file you are downloading.

Example: If i am downloading a Excel file,then the syntax would be

```
ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER=C:\ FILE=Report_{{!NOW:yyyymmdd}}.xls WAIT=YES
```

In your case, only this should be changed **FILE=DownloadReport_{{!NOW:yyyymmdd_hhnnss}}.xls**

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of spaces in that path, maybe iMacros does not allow them and it requires quotes?